# Javascript onclick video object autostart true

Tags: javascript, html, dom, video

How can I change a property of a source element / video object.

In my case I want to change the property autostart from false to true;

html:

```
    <video id="modul_1_video" controls preload="none">
        <source id="modul_1_source" src="../video.mp4" type="video/mp4" autostart="false">
    </video>
```

js: (I do not want to use jquery)

```
    modul_1.onclick = function() {
        console.log("click works");
        document.querySelector("#modul_1_video > source").autostart = true;
    }
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: It doesn't work because the `video` element is already loaded, so it's too late for `autostart` to have any effect. Look at @Hoyen's answer.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just use the play function?

```
modul_1.onclick = function() {
    console.log("click works");
    var video = document.getElementById("#modul_1_video");
    video.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set "autostart" attribute to true on click

```
document.getElementById('modul_1_source').setAttribute('autostart','true');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
modul_1.onclick = function() {
  console.log("click works");           
  document.getElementById("#modul_1_video").setAttribute("autostart","true");
}
```